# NHibernate decimal based UserType precision and scale

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a custom user type that is used to map from a decimal value out of the database to a property on an entity using Fluent NHibernate. The object works correctly as does the mapping to the object but I do not know how to dynamically change the precision and scale of the decimal sql data type so that I can use different precision and scale in different class maps.

Here is an example of my custom type;

```cs
public struct MyCustomType
{
    private readonly decimal value;

    public MyCustomType(decimal value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyCustomType(decimal value)
    {
        return new MyCustomType(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(MyCustomType value)
    {
        return value.value;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return value.ToString(format, provider);
    }
}
```

And here is how I am doing the user type.

```cs
public class MyCustomUserType : IUserType
{
    ...

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        MyCustomType customType = (decimal)rs[names[0]];

        return customType;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var parameter = (IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];
        parameter.Value = (decimal)(MyCustomType)value;
    }

    ...

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        //I think I could hard code the precision and scale here
        get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.Decimal }; }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(MyCustomType); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

And finally this is how I am mapping the object

```cs
public class SomeObjectMappingBase: ClassMap<SomeObject>
{
    protected SomeObjectMappingBase()
    {
        //Currently I do this
        Map(x => x.CustomTypeField).CustomType<MyCustomUserType>();
        //I would like to be able to do this but it does not work
        Map(x => x.CustomTypeField).CustomType<MyCustomUserType>().Scale(10).Precision(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically change"? It can't be dynamically changed as it affects the database schema which we probably don't want to change dynamically. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @NOtherDev I want to be able to use the same type fore multiple ClassMaps, in one I may want to use a Scale and precision of x & y and in another I might want to use a & b. I have updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement IParameterizedUserType or subclass MyCustomUserType for each combination of precision and scale.

Update: unfortunatly i can't think of a way to enable the syntax `.CustomType<SomeObject>().Scale(x).Precision(y)`. instead

option 1 to subclass

```
class MyCustomUserTypeFor10And20 : MyCustomUserType
{
    public override SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.GetDecimal(10, 20) }; }
    }
}


Map(x => x.CustomTypeField).CustomType<MyCustomUserTypeFor10And20>();
```

option 2 parameterizedType

```
<property name="CustomProperty">
   <type name="MyCustomUserType">
      <param name="precision">10</param>
      <param name="scale">20</param>
   </type>
</property>

class MyCustomUserType : IParameterizedType
{
    public void SetParameterValues(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        precision = parameter["precision"];
        scale = parameter["scale"];
    }
}
```

option 3 get somehow this to work: dont map the custom type but set it on the config

```
var mapping = config.GetClassMapping(typeof(...));

foreach (var prop in mapping.PropertyIterator.Where(p => p.Type.ReturnedClass == typeof(decimal)))
{
    prop.Type = new CustomType(typeof(MyCustomType), new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "precision", prop.Type.SqlTypes(null)[0].Precision },
        { "scale", prop.Type.SqlTypes(null)[0].Precision }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did look at the IParameterizedType but didn't see how it should be done, nor could I find any examples. Could you show an example using the above components you mentioned how the scale and precision can be set using the Ma(x => x.FieldName).CustomType<SomeObject>().Scale(x).Precision(y); syntax. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had already done the first option to get the ball rolling but I will have a play with your other suggestions and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: I have had to relent and just have the precision set in the usertype.